# UFT Developer vs. UFT One?

Tags: ui-automation, hp-uft, browser-automation, uft14

I'm currently using UFT One for web automation (mostly screen scraping, form submissions, file uploads, SF Lightning manipulation, etc.) but there is potential for more extensive automation/testing in the future. Our current license is up for renewal shortly and I want to be sure that it makes sense to stick with UFT One over UFT Developer.

Can anyone speak to the major differences between UFT Developer and UFT One?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean for "but there is potential for more extensive automation/testing in the future"?

I’m asking, because to answer you, depends in what your team are aiming for to test.

For example:

We use UFT ONE and Mobile Center, I’m making script's for emulators, browsers, Androids and IOS, pushing queries from the database etc etc...
UFT ONE have a lot to explore, and can do almost every functionality test, and also other kind of test.
Other thing to have in consideration is, look at your team and the skills they have. If you have low programming skills UFT ONE whit the VBscript have a lower curve to learn, since VBscript are easier to understand and get the logic.
If you go at UFT DEV, you can have a huge learning curve. Or you can have programmers that are testing something whit the wrong perspective.

So in the end you have to adjust at your needs, but think well about some questions.

Best luck.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

UFT Developer (previously known as LeanFT) is more developer oriented, you can write your tests in more developer friendly languages (JavaScript, Java, .NET).

UFT One (previously known as UFT) is more "*tester friendly*", it uses VBScript for the test's code but it has a **much** richer feature set and is more established in the testing community.

Answer (score 1):

UFT Developer is used for parallel execution .you can integrate with TestNG .you can use eclipse and all .it has separate recording option.